# Where are the hidden "inline css" in Wordpress located?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, file, inline

This is the code I put-in to style.css in Wordpress:

```
h3.list {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font: bold 15pt Arial,sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    margin: 10px 10px 0;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
}
```

And this is what I can't locate and delete:

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, ul#top-menu a {
    font-family: 'Arvo',Arial,sans-serif !important;
}
```

Please help me locate the file that is causing this. Thank you.

Comment: Which theme are you using? I don't think that any default themes would use a nonstandard font.

Comment: Hello Biziclop. here's my theme http://www.elegantthemes.com/demo/?theme=eList

Comment: Can you give us a link to your page?

Answer (score 6):

Open your site in Chrome and look at Dev Tools (Wrench > Tools > Developer Tools)

Go to the Resources tab and search for that string `h1, h2, h3, h4` and you'll find all instances of it in the files used on the site.

If you know the element to which it applies to (any `h1` will do) you can see all applied styles in the Elements tab and it'll tell you the file name and line number in which that style is defined.

As I suspected, it's in the HTML of the index page.

[image]

Comment: Hi @sachleen and pst - I opened it in chrome and firebug with the inspect element. I went to my h3 and found that the link in the css is written in this format: "/127.0.0.1/myfolder/:83". As you can see it doesn't really point to a particular file...

Comment: So click on it and it'll show you the file it's in and it will highlight the line. It's probably defined in the HTML file itself.

Comment: @sachleen it only loads the home page... This is the template I'm using: http://www.elegantthemes.com/demo/?theme=eList..

Comment: Yep, it's in the HTML. you'll have to remove it from the template code.

Comment: @sachleen - I actually do not see it in the HTML of the demo the OP posted  . maybe it is only on conditional IE ? or it might be also some plugin.

Comment: @ObmerkKronen You have to select the `Arvo` font from the dropdowns.

Comment: @sachleen - Nop ,. strangely it is not there for me ... go figure .

Comment: I don't know.. I just selected Arvo from the dropdowns, hit F12 for dev tools go to Elements tab and search.

Answer (score 2):

Actually just add **!important**, and your css rules will be prioritized and be applied

```
font: bold 15pt Arial,sans-serif !important;
```

Answer (score 1):

Elegant Themes usually have a Theme Options panel for typography. You may be able to change in there rather than in CSS. As others have indicated, Firebug is a great tool for discovering the source of the declaration.

Answer (score 0):

I am basing this off of the demo at: http://elegantthemes.com/preview/eList/

If you look at line 43, you'll notice the following:

```
<style type='text/css'>h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,ul#top-menu a { font-family: 'Arvo', Arial, sans-serif !important;  }</style>
```

That is what is applying the font.  Seeing as it is directly in the `<head>` section and also has `!important` applied, your best bet is just to remove or comment it out.  Then you are free to apply your own fonts however you'd like.

Comment: Just a note -- You can also remove `<link id='arvo' href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />` if you don't plan on using Arvo anywhere else on the site.